# Get a fixed NFC ID in Android

Tags: android, nfc

So here's the thing: That company uses a system that uses NFC Cards to give access to their employees.

I have searched the Web trying to find some way to get a fixed NFC ID. I have found this app in Play Store named "NFC card emulator pro" that seems to do it.

My question is: Is there any way to replicate this app function?

I'm a web developer, this is the first time i'm working on a mobile app... I have no idea from where to start.

The project is simply to create a mobile app that emulates a fixed NFC rfID that works with the access system from this company.

Any ideas? I mainly use Java and Python, i'm learning C++ now.

I tried searching the web for some ideas and found one python library (NFCPY), but not more than that

Comment: Just google "nfc read id java"